# using this in jquery function when using after

Tags: jquery

I often see using this in jquery is `$(this)` but here `this` is used

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4cjnV/)

```
$( "p" ).after(function() {
return "<div>" + this.className + "</div>";
});
```

And if I use like this it won't work

```
$( "p" ).after(function() {
    var cnam = $(this).class();
    return "<div>" + cnam + "</div>";
});
```

And another question why the inserted div is not colored with red background?

Comment: _why the inserted div is not colored with red background?_ Because it doesn't have `foo` className.

Comment: why 'this' is used here as described in jquery it should use $(this) ?

Comment: @undefined when we use .after() as in my example it only selects the className and inserts the text only......

Comment: `$(this)` is wrapper to `this` so that you can use `jQuery` with this

Comment: What do you expect? You don't add any class name to the element, `this` refers to DOM element object in the callback. If you want to create a jQuery object wrap it with `$()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a DOM element, which has the [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className) property.

jQuery doesn't expose a `.class()` method. However, it does have `$(element).prop('class')`

Converting a DOM element to a jQuery object:

```
var $el = $(this);
```

Or the other way around:

```
var el = $(this)[0]; //or var el = $(this).get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have any `class();` in jQuery

You can use

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

To get the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do as such,

```
$( "p" ).after(function() {
    var cnam = $(this).attr('class');
    return "<div>" + cnam + "</div>";
});
```

Jquery don't have such function as `.class()`